# How to sum columns in pairs of a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

For example, if

```
A=[ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

A =

```
 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

How could I obtain this silly trick?

sumA =

```
 1     5     9    13    17
 1     5     9    13    17
 1     5     9    13    17
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sumA = A(:,1:2:end) + A(:,2:2:end);
```

Comment: Nice Oli, it was very simple. The problem is I want to sum not only pairs of elements in a script but a variable number of elements; three, four, five, etc... avoiding using loops. Do you know how to do it? Thanking you again

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this, without the use of a loop, by rearranging to a 3D array and then summing.

The basic idea is to reshape in 2D, transpose, reshape to 3D and then sum back to 2D.

```
%test case

mat     =   repmat([1 2 3 4 5 6],3,1);  %test matrix

nCol    =   3;  %number of columns to sum


if mod( size(mat,2), nCol) == 0

   res     =   sum( reshape( reshape( mat, size(mat,1)*nCol , [] )',[size(mat,2)./nCol, size(mat,1), nCol] ),3)';

end
```

Comment: Nice - **this should be the accepted answer**, given the comment the OP left on the other answer.